# Convert files between DOS and Linux formats

Tags: 16.04

I have a DOS file and I need to convert it to a format that supports Linux.

How can this done?

Tried to use flip. But an error occurs:

> PROJECT.TXT: binary file, not converted

Comment: I would firstly ask your system what type of file it's recognized as, ie. `file PROJECT.TXT` to ensure it's recognized as TEXT or something else.  I'd base what I did next on what that answer is, but `dos2unix` as in @waltinator's answer would be my hoped for conversion method..

Comment: @guiverc `> file PROJECT.TXT`,    `PROJECT.TXT: data`

Comment: It's not text then, you need to peruse the file and work out what type of data file it is (any header, followed by fixed fields? variable fields with markers?, any indexes etc).  Data files are not DOS or LINUX specific; but program specific.  I'd probably resort to writing a conversion routine in perl in your position, but detection of the format needs to be done first.  I don't see it as a DOS file (DOS to me represents text with specific EOL markers; it's a specific but unspecified program data file).

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command `xxd PROJECT.TXT | head`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly ask your system what type of file it's recognized as, ie. `file PROJECT.TXT` to ensure it's recognized as TEXT or something else.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   file lshw_dx6120.txt 
lshw_dx6120.txt: ASCII text
```

Your result from that was it responded DATA.

That result would imply to me it's not text then, and you need to peruse the file and work out what type of data file it is

- a variation of TXT used by some programs, eg. RTF
- is format of file detectable? commonly

  1. a header record
  2. followed by numerous fixed fields?
  3. OR variable length fields with markers?
  4. with any indexes

Data files are not **DOS** or **LINUX** specific; but **program specific**.

I'd probably resort to writing a conversion routine in *perl* in your position, but detection of the format needs to be done first. I don't see it as a DOS file (DOS to me represents text with specific EOL markers; it's a specific but *unspecified* program data file).

If it was text, I'd use `dos2unix` just as in @waltinator's answer.

Looking I found a really old (*if 1987 is old*) DOS file

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   ls -lh /de2900/lan/ws2000/README.TXT 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 guiverc 600 86K Nov 20  1987 /de2900/lan/ws2000/README.TXT
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   file /de2900/lan/ws2000/*.TXT
/de2900/lan/ws2000/README.TXT: data
```

Viewing the file (using `view`) it looks TEXT to me missing only EOL (end-of-line) characters using a ^M (CR) only. I'd use `dos2unix` on that file and expect good results, but what I would do would very much depend on what I saw in the file, and my interpretation of what format file I believe it is. (*if it fails, I can always try again with something else; as I'd convert to a new file only!*)

I copied the old README.TXT file to ~, then tried `dos2unix` and it reported errant ^B chars

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   dos2unix README.TXT 
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x02 found at line 2
dos2unix: Skipping binary file README.TXT
```

I forced it

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   dos2unix -f README.TXT 
dos2unix: converting file README.TXT to Unix format...
```

On closer examination, the README.TXT file in my case is **NOT** text, but a wordstar 2000 file with text extension.   The `file` reported it being data, and it was correct.  The `dos2unix` only converted line-breaks which isn't the only issue.

Comment: The old CP/M & early PC-DOS/MS-DOS versions of wordstar had a much simpler format file, with high-bits to represent end of words (so it could jump forward/back faster as I recall), alas wordstar 2000 was different with a different formatted file. I wish I'd looked for older WS files..

Answer (score 0):

If it's a text file, you can use the command

```
dos2unix /path/to/file
```

If it's not already installed, `sudo apt install dos2unix` will install it.

If it's a .EXE, database, or other Windows-specific binary format, you're out-of-luck.

Use the `file` command to see what kind of file you have.

Read `man dos2unix` and `man file`.

Comment: `dos2unix: Binary character 0x1B found on line 2
dos2unix: Skip binary file PROJECT.TXT`